# Questions about javascript and flash

Tags: javascript, flash

I have a website to develop for a company and, in their instructions, the website must work even the javascript is disabled.
Before beginning the development, I visited this company's main website and it works even the javascript is turned off. But, they are using Flash on their main page and it still run even javascript is turned off (which is obvious).
So, my questions are: why these kind companies require this kind of tests?
It's because javascript is dangerous?
So, in this case, Flash is less dangerous?

Thank you very much.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say whether Flash or Javascript is more likely to expose an exploitable flaw.  But I can tell you that users who turn off Javascript are pretty likely to also turn off Flash.  I would push for a non-Flash solution for your non-Javascript users.

Comment: That what I thought! I turned off javascript and visited a flash website. And it does work! you can try with this webstite: http://www.veolia-transport.com/en/

Comment: I'm not saying that disabling Javascript disables Flash.  I'm saying that most people who do one also do the other.  So, in practice, they go together.  I use NoScript, and that disables Flash as well.

Comment: Ok, I see what you meant! Yes, I think that using NoScript is the "fairest" method to test web apps.
Thank you (I'll wait if somebody else has another point view ;) ).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has something to do with different platforms? old windows mobile phones don't except javascript? and the flash movies you see are that usefull movies? maybe these movies doesn't mather at all? Or maybe it hash something to do with usablity. javascript doesn't had a alternative text and you can give flash a alternative text.

Comment: Javascript does have an alt-text of sort: you can use the noscript element.